# WSO2/Rabbitmq. How to send response to client after sending message to queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

Is it possible to send synchronous response to client after sending message to queue?

```
<proxy name="VssService" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log description="LOG REQUEST" level="full"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <send>
               <endpoint key="VssEP"/>
            </send>   
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, in this case, you will have to Implement a JMS Dual channel scenario. Take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/jms_examples/dual-channel-http-to-jms/) and [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/examples/rabbitmq_examples/request-response-rabbitmq/).